# Python dynamically compute a list with no duplicates using only list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is sort of a ridiculous and weird use case but bear with me, I have this list comprehension:

```
"reading_types": [
    {
        "name": rt.reading_type,
        "value": rt.reading_type_id,
    }
    for unit in item.units
    for rt in unit.reading_types
],
```

in a backend api call. It works great *except* that there will almost always be duplicates in the end result. How can I ensure that no duplicates are returned?

This is actually happening inside another list comprehension, and I can't reference the list at any point to remove duplicates so I must do so within the list comprehension itself.

I've tried using a `set`:

```
set([
    {
        "name": rt.reading_type,
        "value": rt.reading_type_id,
    }
    for unit in item.units
    for rt in unit.reading_types
])
```

but this results in the error: `unhashable type: dict`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the idea is to make your structures *hashable* without destroying them too much so you can restore them back as how they were.

You could convert your dictionaries to `dict_items` then to `tuples` (now we can put that in a `set` because data is hashable), apply a `set` on that, and convert back to dictionary:

```
input_list = [{"name":"name1","id":"id1"},{"name":"name2","id":"id2"},
{"name":"name1","id":"id1"}]

output_list = [dict(items) for items in {tuple(a.items()) for a in input_list}]
```

This works because values of the sub-dicts are hashable (strings). If they were dictionaries, we'd have to convert them too.

result:

```
[{'id': 'id1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'id': 'id2', 'name': 'name2'}]
```

another solution (by Jon Clements) that doesn't use a `set` but builds a dictionary (using a dictionary comprehension) & uses key unicity to clobber duplicates, then extract only values:

```
list({tuple(d.items()):d for d in input_list}.values())
```

Comment: wow this works great! I have a million questions though, not super familiar with python, why tuples? Why wrap them in brackets? And what is the `:d for d` syntax with the colon? If you could explain any of this further I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a dictionary inside the `set`.  As immutable objects, `namedtuple`s are hashable, which dictionaries are not. You can also use a set comprehension directly:

```
from collections import namedtuple

reading_type = namedtuple("reading_type", ["name", "value"])

{reading_type(rt.reading_type, rt.reading_type_id) 
    for unit in item.units
    for rt in unit.reading_types}
```

Comment: Python 3.6 has a new (IMHO better) syntax for named tuple, even tho the old ones still work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a list comprehension, but you can use the `itertools` [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in 3rd party libraries, e.g. [`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen):

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

input_list = [{"name":"name1","id":"id1"},{"name":"name2","id":"id2"},
              {"name":"name1","id":"id1"}]

res = list(unique_everseen(input_list, key=lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))))

print(res)

[{'name': 'name1', 'id': 'id1'}, {'name': 'name2', 'id': 'id2'}]
```

The trick is to make sure you can hash your dictionaries, which we perform by converting each dictionary to a tuple of sorted tuples. Internally, the algorithm works by maintaining a "seen" `set` of values and yielding only values which do not appear in the `set`, adding them otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your entire list in another comprehension to `repr` each entry, and use `set` on that:

```
set([repr(val) for val in [...]])
```

Comment: edit: actually this isn't great since `repr` seems to just return stringified objects and I don't want that